# difference between "cleaning a room" and "tidying a room"?

Tags: meaning

What's the difference between "cleaning up a room" and "tidying a room"?

Is it like cleaning, unlike tidying, involves wiping, sweeping and mopping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what sense of [*clean*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clean#h3) you are using.

From Merriam-Webster:

> **1a** : to make clean: such as
>   **(1)** : to rid of dirt, impurities, or extraneous matter

This sense mainly involves making a place hygienic. It would involve scrubbing, sweeping, and mopping.

> **b** REMOVE, ERADICATE —usually used with *up* or *off*
>   // *clean up* that mess

This *can* be used in the first sense (cleaning up spilled milk), but it can also be used in the sense of making something neat or presentable (cleaning up a disordered pile of books).

As for [*tidy*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tidy) (also from Merriam-Webster):

> : to put in order

So, *tidying a room* is the equivalent of the second sense of *cleaning a room* here—but it's not the same as the first sense of *cleaning a room*.

---

In short, it's based on context. You will not be able to tell from just the words *clean the room* if they mean the same thing as *tidy the room* or not. More information will need to be provided.

Comment: +1 I think there may be a regional component as well. My parents demanded that I "clean" my room, while the British children's shows my daughter watches tend to feature "tidying".